# Passing string literals in K&R C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

So let's say you have a putchar function that takes a single character as an argument and prints that single character to the screen: putchar(char c).

Then let's say you want to build a function on top of that to print strings: printf(char a[]) or printf(char *a).

In K&R C (so pre-C89), is it legal to pass a string literal to a printf function that takes array or pointer arguments?

It hasn't been working for me. The function is not printing anything when I run the program.

Specifically:

```
bputchar(char c)
{
        #asm 
                mov ax, #0x0000
                mov ds, ax
                mov ah, #0x0e
                mov bx, sp
                mov al, 2[bx]
                xor bx, bx
                int #0x10
        #endasm
}

bprintf(char *a)
{
    unsigned char i;
    i = 0;
    for (a; *a != '\0'; a++)
    {
        i = *a;
        bputchar(i);
    }
}

/* OR (ALTERNATE PRINTF) */

bprintf(char a[])
{
    unsigned char i;
    i = 0;
    for (i; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        bputchar(a[i]);
    }
}

prompt()
{
    bprintf("prompt:\\");
}
```

Prompt() contains the string to be printed.

But this prints nothing regardless of which bprintf variant is used. I know the bputchar function works. Is there something wrong with passing a string to a function in K&R C? Or is there some other problem with my code? I'm guessing it's the latter, because K&R C First Edition has examples of their printf function working with strings passed as arguments.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's totally legal, but I don't see anything particularly wrong that would break this either.

Comment: In `bprintf(char *a)`, what is the purpose of `i`? Why not simply `while (*a) putchar(*a++);`? To test your code, replace `bputchar` with `putchar` -- Do you still receive no output?

Comment: Yet another [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?  What does K&R have to do with any of this?  Are you really using a pre-C standards compiler?  If you're simply using K&R as your reference manual, it still doesn't have anything to do with your particular problem.  You are trying to print something and failing.  Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: The bprintf function -- compiled and run on Windows using a modern (C89+) compiler and using putchar instead of bputchar -- works. That being said, I know that bputchar (which prints using bios interrupts) also works on its own. I can post screenshot proof if it would help.

Comment: @jwdonahue I am indeed using a K&R C compiler -- bcc. That's why I asked.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a wet blanket here, but how is using `#asm` and `#endasm` connected to "K & R C?" I thought they had `asm { ... }`?

Comment: LOL, K&R wrote compilers for computers that have been in the Smithsonian for decades.  Are you using Bruce's C Compiler?  K&R was never a standard, it was a tutorial for the C language, that happens to predate the ANSI and ISO standards.

Comment: In other words, there was never a K&R standard.  There were K&R C compilers back in the day, but you are not using one of those.

Comment: Yeah Bruce's C Compiler. Sorry for the bad reference to K&R C; I'd read in a few places that the compiler accepts only "K&R C." I'm messing around with a 16-bit console program. @Adrian Mole: the bputchar function itself doesn't implicate K&R C. I was wondering about passing strings to the bprintf function.

Comment: So, read [ask], and [edit] your post accordingly.  Adding any reference to K&R C in your title or OP body is just an invitation to be scorned.  The salient points are that your code isn't working and you are using Bruce's C compiler.  You also aren't showing us the includes or the compiler/linker command lines you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
printf("%s", "literal string");
```

works well for me. Must work well for you.

Second: Has been long time but I think your asm code is not correct, you must to call:

```
int 80h
```

in order to pass a command to the kernel. You must to know how to do a Linux System Call.

Please, check in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm

for more details.

HTH.
I think